# voxel animation to Godot

Tags: animation, voxel, godot, magicavoxel

I am doing a voxel game in Godot. Using magicavoxel . Is there a fine way to do voxel animation without rigging in blender. May be frame animation of 3d model in Godot(is that possible or do we animate only 2dscreenshots of the model?)Because there is no proper export format for animated model in magicavoxel.

Or is there another good tool which allows to export animated voxel models, ready to use?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a little late to this question but if anyone is still looking for a fix this could work: If you want to animate frame by frame, one way that you could do this is by exporting each frame to an .obj from magicavoxel. Then load the model one after another switching them out every couple of frames. It might be a bit slow but if you really want to use this kind of animation style then this is probably the way to go.